# How to use WKT to draw polygon in qgis?

Tags: gis, data-science, qgis

I have a CSV file with a data field which contains data like bellow

> POLYGON ((79.87749999947846 6.997500000409782, 79.88249999947845
> 6.997500000409782, 79.88249999947845 7.002500000409782, 79.87749999947846 7.002500000409782, 79.87749999947846 6.997500000409782))

I want to draw a polygon by using this data field in qgis. How can i do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For example,I have a csv with two columns "**Id**" and "**geom**" that geom have your POLYGON example,

[image]

Go to ***layer->Add Layer->Add delimited text Layer*** and browse your csv and the geometry field combobox select the column that have your wkt data,in my case is "**geom**" and **Geometry definition** select (**WKT**) option

[image]

The result is:

[image]

In another way, using Python:

```
uri ='file:///C://Users//fjraga//Desktop//test.csv?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4326&wktField=%s' % (",", "geom")
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Test','delimitedtext')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

But if you only want load this WKT geometry using QGIS python console,try with this:

```
wkt = "POLYGON ((79.87749999947846 6.997500000409782, 79.88249999947845 6.997500000409782, 79.88249999947845 7.002500000409782, 79.87749999947846 7.002500000409782, 79.87749999947846 6.997500000409782))"

temp = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "result", "memory")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(temp)

temp.startEditing()
geom = QgsGeometry()
geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt)
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(geom)
temp.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])
temp.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Thanks - the python code worked in QGIS 3.x once I changed QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance to QgsProject.instance

Answer (score 2):

You copy your text into the clipboard.

And then:

1. Open QGIS
2. Open the "Edit" Menu
3. Enter the "Insert Objects as"/"Insert Features as" sub-menu
4. Choose either vector or temporary layer
5. Select the correct coordinate system

And you are done.

It is as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

**Creating new layers from the clipboard using well-known text (WKT)**

Features that are on the clipboard can be pasted into a new layer. To do this, Select some features, copy them to the clipboard, and then paste them into a new layer using Edit ‣ Paste Features as ‣ and choosing:

New Vector Layer…: the Save vector layer as… dialog appears (see Creating new layers from an existing layer for parameters)

or Temporary Scratch Layer…: you need to provide a name for the layer

A new layer, filled with selected features and their attributes is created (and added to map canvas).

> Note
>
> Creating layers from the clipboard is possible with features selected
>   and copied within QGIS as well as features from another application,
>   as long as their geometries are defined using **well-known text (WKT)**.

Reference:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-new-layers-from-the-clipboard